# Horas del día en eje x de una gráfica boxplot en python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Estoy intentado graficar una serie de datos usando boxplot y poniendo las horas del día en el eje X.

He conseguido hacer plot de la serie de datos, con el siguiente código, en dónde "dataToBoxPlot" es mi serie de datos:

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.set_title('Basic Plot')
ax3.boxplot(dataToBoxPlot)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto le quiero poner las horas del día (empezando desde 00:00 hasta las 23:00) en el eje X. Para llegar a esto he intentado lo siguiente:

```
hoursString = ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00',
               '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00',
               '22:00', '23:00']
hoursToAxis = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in hoursString]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Basic Plot')
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax1.boxplot(hoursToAxis, dataToBoxPlot)
plt.show()
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

**¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? ¿Cómo puedo obtener en el X del boxplot las horas del día?** GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución consiste en llamar [`ax.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) con `hoursString`. Internamente, el eje `x` en esta caso son números `1,2,3,...` (habitualmente con un eje con textos es `0,1,2,...`; no sé por que los `boxplot` empiecen con `1`).

Un código para demonstrar el uso:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# alguna cosa random que parece un poco el plot del ejemplo
dataToBoxPlot = [45+np.random.pareto(10, 100)*500*(2-(14-i)**2/200)  for i in range(24)]
# los textos '00:00', '01:00', '02:00', ...
hoursString = [f'{i:02}:00' for i in range(24)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
ax.boxplot(dataToBoxPlot)
plt.ylim(0, 500)  # limitar y, para que los 'outliers' no ocupan la mayoría del espacio
ax.set_xticklabels(hoursString) # o plt.xticks(range(1,25), hoursString)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo del plot]

Ahora, el error `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'`. Pues, un [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) es un momento en el tiempo. Es decir, un día en un año particular en una hora particular. Estos momentos en el tiempo no se puede sumar ni multiplicar. `boxplot` cree que su primer parámetro son los datos, y quiere calcular todas las medidas con estos datos. Pero Python no le permite hacer cálculos con los `datetime`.

Para calcular con un `datetime` se necesita un intervalo de tiempo, un [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).